# Can we make simple rest calls from a normal html page?

Tags: html, rest

Is it possible to make simple rest calls from a normal html page without any other scriptlets .if no then can we make it using any scriplets .
eg: I have a normal html page that makes rest calls (get) to another html page that is online and displays the results.

Comment: Define "normal html page". What technologies do you want to use? Why?

Comment: HTML is a markup language used to present information. You can't use HTML to communicate with an API. However you can get requested information on server side using a PHP, JAVA, .NET, ..., or on client side with Javascript, but be aware of Cross Domain Requests, when getting data on client side.